# SELECT All rows of data but eliminate rows with duplicate data in single column

Tags: php, mysql

Would like to grab ALL data from this row, but trying to weed out the duplicate data.

Current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cDeviceRegistrationID) FROM tblUsers WHERE cDeviceRegistrationID > '';
```

This returns only the one column of data, but I would like to get all the other data too.

This isn't working for me as it will still return rows with the same cDeviceRegistrationID:

```
SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE cDeviceRegistrationID > '';
```

Comment: Which data do you want as unique?  cDeviceRegistrationID?  Or all three of the columns you want to select?  For example, is it acceptable to get (1, 1, 1) and (1, 1, 2), or would you only want (1, 1, 1)?

Comment: Just want it to select rows with a distinct cDeviceRegistrationID, however, I would still like to grab all data in that row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE cDeviceRegistrationID > '' GROUP BY cDeviceRegistrationID
```

This method is preferred since you can take advantage of indexes (index cDeviceRegistrationID).

Comment: This works. Thanks. Is there a way to have all usernames associated with the cDeviceRegistrationID shown in the same row of data?